# Research: is it possible to send (web or mobile) push notifications without opting in?

Tags: push-notification, web-push, identification

I'm doing some research on different push notification strategies. I'm 99% sure this isn't possible but I just want that extra 1% surety.

Is it possible to send a web or mobile push notification when a mobile phone enters a geofenced area without a specific app installed on the phone or without the user being on a specific website (basically they haven't opted in to anything)?

Comment: It depends on the OS. iOS or Android ?

Comment: Is it ever possible? And how?

Comment: On iOS 13 (currently in beta), it'll be possible using the native shortcut application.

Comment: No I don’t think that’ll do what I’m investigating. I want to send an unknown user a message when they enter an area

Comment: You can't do this.

Comment: Probably not through the conventional "push notification", but you might be interested in [WAP Based Location Services](https://www.w3.org/Mobile/posdep/MotorolaW3C.html) and [Bluetooth and WAP Push Based Location-Aware Mobile Advertising System](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221234587_Bluetooth_and_WAP_Push_Based_Location-Aware_Mobile_Advertising_System).